# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronous multiple requests not executed

Tags: ios, asynchronous, queue, httprequest, nsurlconnection

I was sending 10 requests of url (in a for in loop) to web service

and expected to get 10 JSON format data as return separately

here's my code:

```
NSArray *reqArray = [10 requests of url inside];
NSMutableArray * saveArray = [prepare to store 10 JSON data in here];
NSInteger counter = [reqArray count];

for (NSURLRequest *request in reqArray) {
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               NSDictionary *result1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                               NSDictionary *result2 = [result1 objectForKey:@"keyForValueIWant"];
                               [saveArray addObject:result2];
                            counter -- ;
                               if (counter == 0) {
                                   NSLog(@"all done");

                               }
                           }];

}
```

the completionHandler never gets executed and I always get nothing in return.

is there anything I misunderstand bout the NSURLConnetion or I did it wrong?

any advice would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I found code gets executed after all the other code in viewDidLoad (where I put it) are done

even I tried to wrap it in **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}**,

what could make it work immediately whenever I call it? sendSynchronous request?

Comment: Then, what's happening?, the code inside the completionHandler is nerver executing?, or is executing with a delay?, because that is an asynchronous request, and that is the way it works, when you get the response from the server, the completionHandler block executes.

Comment: @gabuh   the code inside gets executed...but I need it be completed before I run the other code. trying sending synchronous request now...terribly stuck my program :/

Comment: Sending a synchronous request in your main thread is not a good idea. You should think how to structure your code to work with async requests. You are loading an array, and you need that array for your program to work. For what are you using it?, loading a tableView? you could trigger something in your completion block to reload whatever depends on the contents of that array....

Comment: @gabuh open another queue to run this loop in background at the exact point I want it , guess I should've go deep in GCD...thanks then. btw, it'd be great if you got time for my another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021281/ios-table-view-cell-load-images-in-the-order-of-row-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are starting those connections off the main loop, try with:

```
NSArray *reqArray = [10 requests of url inside];
NSMutableArray * saveArray = [prepare to store 10 JSON data in here];
NSInteger counter = [reqArray count];

for (NSURLRequest *request in reqArray) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)     {
                           NSDictionary *result1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                           NSDictionary *result2 = [result1 objectForKey:@"keyForValueIWant"];
                           [saveArray addObject:result2];
                        counter -- ;
                           if (counter == 0) {
                               NSLog(@"all done");

                           }
                       }];
    });
}
```

Because NSURLConnection needs a runloop to execute, if the runloop ends, the connections ends.