# ios table view cell load images in the order of row index

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, afnetworking

Configuring cells in a table view, I use the

```
-(void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest placeholderImage:(UIImage *)
```

method from **AFNetworking** to load cell images ( put it in cellForRowAtIndexPath ) from web

that users won't get stuck scrolling while it's loading.

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

the question is that every image show up in random order

because this method sends asynchronous request,

yet I want them to be displayed one after another,

such as the image in row 1 cell must show up after image in row 0 cell is shown,
and so on

it's like the loading could be asynchronous( and it must be)...

but the display should be synchronous (in order!)

is there an easy way to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why? Images are different sizes so will download at different speeds. And some may fail. Why prevent the user from seeing some because of these issues?

Comment: trying to make it looks smooth, of course nothing wrong with the different showing...but, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the name of the images in an array and access it in **cellForItemAtIndexPath()** method of the UITableView. By this way you will get the proper order of the images. You should not display images one after another because of different sizes of the images(for example - if the image size is in megabytes, it would take a lot of time to load, that time can be used to load another images)

```
NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"]];
[cell.imgMyPhoto setImageWithURL:photoURL placeholderImage:nil usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show them one after another, you can use this code to set execution order to FIFO which will give u desired output.

```
[[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] imageDownloader] setExecutionOrder:SDWebImageDownloaderFIFOExecutionOrder];
```

You can use this method as mentioned above by Utsav Parikh

```
NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"]];
[cell.imgLogo setImageWithURL :photoURL placeholderImage : kPhotoPlaceholder usingActivityIndicatorStyle : UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

but dont forget to import the header file

```
#import "UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h"
```